# what is this "blabla" from Java point of view?

Tags: java

I am wondering if

```
String s = new String("blabla");
```

is exactly the same as

```
String s = "blabla";
```

I think for the first one this constructor of the String class is called:

```
 public String(char value[]) {
        this.value = Arrays.copyOf(value, value.length);
    }
```

but not sure if it's the same for the second one.

In other words, what is this "blabla" from Java point of view?

So while using `String s = "blabla";` is `s` a new stance of `String` class? and if yes which of its constructors is called?

Comment: "I think for the first one this constructor of the String class is called:" no. `"blabla"` is a string literal, which is a `String`, not a `char[]`. This constructor is not the one called.

Comment: @AndyTurner so probably this shoud be the one:  `public String(String original) {
        this.value = original.value;
        this.hash = original.hash;
    }`

Comment: @AndyTurner does the second one call any constructor ?

Comment: that would be the one.

Comment: yes, a constructor has to be called at some point; it's just not called where it appears in the code, unlike with `new String(...)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner so which constructor  and when is it called?

Comment: I've never cared enough to check which constructor is called; but it's going to be called when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually as you may already know `String` is an immutable class which means once it's intialized it can't be changed anymore so this is exactly why there is two why of creating Strings.

1. `String s = "blabla"` : Here this String is created and pushed to the String Constant Pool if it's not already exist.
2. `String s = new String("blabla")` : However like this a new String is created each time, without checking if it's already exist in the Pool.

Note : that `String s = new String("blabla").intern()` is equivalent to `String s = "blabla"` .

Comment: so if there is nothing in the pool (there are no string created yet) then `String s = "blabla"` creates a new instance? and if so, what is the called constructor?

Comment: The constructor being called in this case is `public String(char value[])` to make sure put a break point at this constructor and run the debug mode.